# VBA Ribbon validate imageMso

Tags: excel, vba, icons, ribbonx

I'm creating a custom ribbon in Excel, and I'm using ImageMso's for icons. I downloaded the full list of Icons from Microsoft, and tried to create a menu that displays them all for me to choose, but some of them are not displaying.

Is there any way to validate if an imageMso code does not work with the current version of windows, and display a placeholder in it's place instead of a blank icon?

[image]

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the short answer is no, but I also haven't investigated or attempted to resolve it with any great tenacity. If it doesn't show up I will retry with a different icon.

Note that I am not an expert by any means, but have been playing around with customUI for a while.

There is a great free Add-In I found that helps with speeding up the whole process of identifying suitable icons. It's worth checking it out. 
https://www.spreadsheet1.com/how-to-use-imagemso-icons-in-excel.html

Josh

PS. I hear this is particularly an issue going into the Office 2019.